# global level tags for gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, cicd

What I am trying to achieve:

In my gitlab-ci file, I would like each and every jobs to have this:

```
  tags:
    - type/docker
    - os/linux
```

What did I try:

I have hundreds of jobs in my file.
As of right now, for each one of them, I am duplicating this:

```
some-first-job:
  stage: security
  tags:
    - type/docker
    - os/linux

some-second-job:
  image: 
  stage: security
  tags:
    - type/docker
    - os/linux

some-hundread-job:
  stage: security
  tags:
    - type/docker
    - os/linux
```

Question is there a way to set the tag globally, such as:

```
tags:
  - type/docker
  - os/linux

some-first-job:
  stage: security

some-second-job:
  image: 
  stage: security

some-hundread-job:
  stage: security
```

This tags is for the gitlab runner to pick it up.

Is there any way to "refactor the tags" so every job can benefit from it?

Or maybe there is a way to configure the gitlab runner globally?

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to the solution, just put the tags under `default:` block like this:

```
default:
  tags:
    - type/docker
    - os/linux
```

more information is available on their documentation - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#default